# Renumbering a Work Breakdown Structure (WBS) in a datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, iteration

A multi-level WBS the users were able to delete some tasks that are not applicable to their project.  Goal is to renumber the entire WBS so that no numbers are skipped.  Example: 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.4 - number 1.1.3 was deleted. Each WBS element may or may not have child elements that need to be renumbered as well.
I have the data in a datatable, fields: WBS_ID, WBSNo, ParentID, ParentNo, SortKey(the original WBS Number) and Notes.  WBS_ID is the UID, ParentID is the WBS_ID of the parent WBS element. First element of the WBS has a null value in the ParentID field.

I cannot seem to grasp how to make an iterative function call to create the WBS number.

```
Dim dTb As New DataTable
    Using Conn
        Conn.Open()
        Using dad As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(vSqlStr, Conn)
            dad.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ProjectID", SqlDbType.Int)
            dad.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Revision", SqlDbType.Int)
            dad.SelectCommand.Parameters("@ProjectID").Value = vProjectID
            dad.SelectCommand.Parameters("@Revision").Value = vRevision
            dad.Fill(dTb) 'Now we have a table with all the elements .
        End Using
        Conn.Close()
    End Using
    'Now work with the datatable
    'WBS_ID, WBSNo, WBSLevel, ParentID, ParentNo, SortKey, Notes
    dTb.DefaultView.Sort = "SortKey ASC"
    dTb = dTb.DefaultView.ToTable
    Dim vRowCount As Int16
    vRowCount = dTb.Rows.Count
    Dim vCurRow As Int16 = 0
    For x = 0 To vRowCount - 1
        If Not IsDBNull(dTb.Rows(x)("ParentID")) Then

        Else
            dTb.Rows(x)("WBSNo") = "1"
        End If
        dTb.Rows(x)("Notes") = dTb.Rows(x)("Notes") & vbCrLf & "<<< Old WBS No. = " & dTb.Rows(x)("SortKey")
    Next
```

Renumber the WBS, starting with "1", each child of an element would be numbered with the parent number, plus a period (.) then sequentially starting with 1; each child could have children.

Comment: I'm looking for a recursive function - for each record, if it has children, the WBSNo = the parent WBSNo + "." + incremental number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a recursive sub-routine to update the datatable, then another routine to update the database.

```
Sub RenumberChildren(vParentID As Int16, vParentWBSNo As String)
    Dim ChildCount As Int16 = 0
    For x = 0 To dTb.Rows.Count - 1

        If Not IsDBNull(dTb.Rows(x)("ParentID")) Then
            If dTb.Rows(x)("ParentID") = vParentID Then
                ChildCount += 1
                dTb.Rows(x)("WBSNo") = vParentWBSNo & "." & ChildCount
                RenumberChildren(dTb.Rows(x)("WBS_ID"), dTb.Rows(x)("WBSNo"))
            End If
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```